# C-like for loop with float values and bc, unexpected ";"

Tags: bash

I'm a bash beginner and I can't spot the error in this loops, and bash just gives me `syntax error: ';' unexpected`, not really useful...

```
# log2(x) = ln(x) / ln(2)
for (( j=$(echo "l($i) / l(2)" | bc -l) ;
    $(echo "scale=$SCALE; j < (2*$i)" | bc) == 1 ;
    j=$(echo "scale=$SCALE; $j + 1/$step" | bc) ))
do
        foo...
done
```

What I want to do is something like this, using a C-like pseudo-code:

```
integer i

for ( float j = log2(i) ; j < 2*i ; j += 1/8 )
    ...
```

Maybe there are better ways to do this, I don't know. Can't find anything here or on Google... well, it's hard to find a solution searching "syntax error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for (( ... ))` notation expects shell arithmetic notation, not regular Bash commands. (I mean, shell arithmetic does support expansions such as `$(...)`, but that's a recipe for total confusion.) Since shell arithmetic won't work for you (it's only for integers), you're better off using a `while`-loop, something like this:

```
j=$(bc -l <<< "l($i) / l(2)")
while [[ $( bc <<< "scale=$SCALE; $j < 2 * $i" ) = 1 ]] ; do
    ...
    j=$(bc <<< "scale=$SCALE; $j + 0.125")
done
```

Comment: Shell arithmetic also only supports integers!

Comment: @tc.: I'm not sure I follow; which part of my answer are you commenting on? (Note that I *did* write "shell arithmetic won't work for you (it's only for integers)".)

Comment: This is NOT shell arithmetic. `bc` is in fact an __external__ tool, which does all the math stuff and then returns a TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) to the `bash`. "Shell arithmetic" only covers math operations done by `bash` *built-in* commands and operators. An this, as you correctly pointed out, is not possible with floating point numbers.

Comment: Maybe, but I just wanted to make this clear once and for all, because it's often confused by bash hackers. To be frank, it's easy to mistake `bc` as a bash built-in command. You won't know unless you've finally opened up the `man` page of `bc`. :)